# Prove $\sqrt{2a+b^3}+\sqrt{2b+c^3}+\sqrt{2c+a^3}\le 3\sqrt{3}$ for $a^2+b^2+c^2=3.$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, buffalo-way

**Problem.** Given non-negative real numbers $a,b,c$ satisfying $a^2+b^2+c^2=3.$ Prove that
$$\sqrt{2a+b^3}+\sqrt{2b+c^3}+\sqrt{2c+a^3}\le 3\sqrt{3}.$$
Naturally by using Cauchy-Schwarz, we need to show that$$2(a+b+c)+a^3+b^3+c^3\le 9,$$
which is not true when $ a=b\rightarrow 1^{-}.$

I also tried$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{2a+b^3}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{2a+b^3}{2a^2+b^2}\cdot (2a^2+b^2)}\le \sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\frac{2a+b^3}{2a^2+b^2}\cdot 3(a^2+b^2+c^2),}$$which saves occuring equality but $$\frac{2a+b^3}{2a^2+b^2}+\frac{2b+c^3}{2b^2+c^2}+\frac{2c+a^3}{2c^2+a^2}\le 3$$ is already wrong when $a=b=0.99.$

I hope you give some better approach using Holder, AM-GM, etc. Maybe the BW helps for the rest.

Thank you for paying attention.

Comment: If we assume $S = \sqrt{2a+b^3} + \sqrt{2b+c^3} + \sqrt{2c+a^3}$ then using *Cauchy-Schwarz ineqaulity* we get $S^2 \leq 3(a^3+b^3+c^3 + 2(a+b+c))$ then using $AM-GM$ we get $S^2 \leq 3(2(a+b+c)+3abc)$ Now I am also stuck :(

Comment: Yes, it leads to wrong inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some thoughts.**

**Fact 1.** Let $x, y, z \ge 0$ with $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + \frac56x^2y^2z^2 \le \frac{23}{6}$. Then $x + y + z \le 3$.
(It is verified by *Mathematica*. Similar to: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4749621/finding-small-max-limits-abc-3-frac1-sqrta2-3a3-frac1-sqrtb/4813198#4813198).)

Now, let
$$x := \sqrt{\frac{2a + b^3}{3}}, \quad
y := \sqrt{\frac{2b + c^3}{3}}, \quad z := \sqrt{\frac{2c + a^3}{3}}.$$
We have
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + \frac56x^2y^2z^2 \le \frac{23}{6}$$
which is equivalent to
$$621 - 54(a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + 2a + 2b + 2c) - 5(b^3 + 2a)(c^3 + 2b)(a^3 + 2c)\ge 0. \tag{1}$$
(1) is verified by *Mathematica*. Is there a nice proof?

By Fact 1, we have $x + y + z \le 3$.

Comment: Nice idea. I also to try: Let $x, y, z \ge 0$ with $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + \frac34x^2y^2z^2 \le \frac{15}{4}$. Then $x + y + z \le 3$ but it failed.

Comment: By the way, is Mathematica absolutely correct in inequalities? I think it might make a mistake.

Comment: @youthdoo I use Mathematica to verify the inequality. This is not the end. At this stage, I will write "some thoughts". Then I will find a human verifiable proof. This time, I write "proof".

Comment: @TATAbox You should not accept my answer since I don't have a nice proof of (1). I think Michael Rozenberg's better (already upvoted before I posted my answer).

Comment: I think his final step is hard.

Comment: @TATAbox Anyway, hope there is a nice proof of (1).

Comment: Did you use BW?

Comment: @TATAbox I would edit it in some days.

Comment: I tried $(1)$. It is complicated.

Comment: @TATAbox Yes, no real progress.

Answer (score 2):

By C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{2a+b^3}\leq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\frac{2a+b^3}{3a+5b+c}\sum_{cyc}(3a+5b+c)}=3\sqrt{(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}\frac{2a+b^3}{3a+5b+c}}$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}\frac{2a+b^3}{3a+5b+c}\leq3,$$ which is true, but my solution is not so good: homogenization and B-W.

About BW see here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h522084p2942645

Comment: You used Bacteria skill. Thank you.

Comment: What is B-W and how can we complete the proof?